# How can I get the height and width and length of an SVG path using Python?

Tags: python, svg

I have an svg with tons of paths like this basically:

```
<path fill="#fb6430" opacity="1.00" d=" M 0.70 0.00 L 14.60 0.00 C 16.36 3.76 19.56 6.54 21.77 9.99 C 21.37 11.15 20.65 12.15 20.02 13.20 C 18.65 11.77 17.81 9.99 17.51 8.04 C 16.28 8.93 15.13 9.92 14.08 11.01 C 13.93 9.08 13.77 7.16 13.62 5.23 C 13.03 5.22 11.84 5.20 11.25 5.19 C 11.35 6.73 11.45 8.26 11.58 9.79 C 10.84 9.90 9.37 10.13 8.63 10.24 C 7.87 9.37 7.10 8.51 6.36 7.63 C 6.08 7.25 5.53 6.51 5.25 6.13 C 3.75 4.08 2.19 2.06 0.70 0.00 Z" />
```

i want to get the height, width, area, length, and anything else I can basically from this path. Is there any python library? Or is there something I am overlooking where I could just do it manually?

Comment: If you could use Bezier Lines you could probably easily estimate the size of your path. Otherwise I don't know of any library supporting what you need. Most Libraries like pysvg only support primitives.

Answer (score 11):

You can use [svgpathtools](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/svgpathtools) to find measurements like these (assuming I know what you mean).

```
# create svgpathtools Path objects from an SVG file
from svgpathtools import svg2paths
paths, attributes = svg2paths('some_svg_file.svg')

# let's take the first path as an example
mypath = paths[0]

 # Let's find its length
print("length = ", mypath.length())

# Find height, width
xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax = mypath.bbox()
print("width = ", xmax - xmin)
print("height = ", ymax - ymin)

# Let's find the area enclosed by the path (assuming the path is closed)
try:
    print("area = ", mypath.area())
except AssertionError:
    print("This path is not closed!")
    # if you want a notion of area for an open path, 
    # you could use the bounding box area.
    print("height*width = ", (ymax - ymin)*(xmax - xmin))
```

Comment: Thanks for writing the package!

Comment: It seems working for single path, how to find for bounding box for combination of path?

Comment: @rcShahi `combined_path = Path(*[segment for p in list_of_paths for segment in p._segments])` will combine a list of paths into a single path (paths can be discontinuous).

Comment: This package looks very powerful, thanks! I feel stupid : where can I find the corresponding API? I knew there must be some kind of "bounding box method", I tried `bounding_box()`, `boundingbox()`, and had to google to find `bbox()`.

Comment: @EricDuminil not sure what you're asking.

Comment: @mathandy: Sorry if that wasn't clear. I couldn't find the API documentation for svgpathtools, generated from docstrings. Something like https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.html , for example listing every method available for a Path instance.

Comment: @EricDuminil there is currently no auto-generated documentation -- you have to look in the code.  That said, there's lots of in-code documentation and there are examples for much of the functionality in [the README](https://github.com/mathandy/svgpathtools).  I hope that helps!