# Get bounding box of SVG drawing

Tags: python, svg, bounding-box

I would like to extract the bounding box of a SVG drawing.

Since Python is already available on the system and also used to perform other tasks, I don't want to use JavaScript or any other language. My understanding is if the bounding box of a single element can be calculated (but I don't know how).

The bounding box of the whole drawing is just the minimum and maximum x,y values a of all elements, hence probably the bounding boxes of all elements need to be calculated.

I am a Python beginner, but `svgwrite` is probably not the right module and so far I was scared by the installation of `rsvg` on a Windows system.

Comment: I haven't used it but there's something called [svgpathtools](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/svgpathtools/1.0.1).

Comment: thanks, @BillBell, at least it promises "find a bounding box for a path or segment". I will try...

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35260742/how-can-i-get-the-height-and-width-and-length-of-an-svg-path-using-python

Comment: how to get bbox for combination of path, it seems working with only single path

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There may be a more direct approach to achieve this, but something like this should meet your requirements.

You can convert your file to a list of path objects with the `svg2paths` method and iterate through them.

```
from svgpathtools import svg2paths

def get_bbox(svg_file):
    paths, _ = svg2paths(svg_file)

    for i, path in enumerate(paths):
        if i == 0:
            # Initialise the overall min-max with the first path
            xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax = path.bbox()
        else:
            # Expand bounds to match path bounds if needed
            p_xmin, p_xmax, p_ymin, p_ymax = path.bbox()
            xmin = p_xmin if p_xmin < xmin else xmin
            xmax = p_xmax if p_xmax > xmax else xmax
            ymin = p_ymin if p_ymin < ymin else ymin
            ymax = p_ymax if p_ymax > ymax else ymax
    
    print(xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)

get_bbox("myfile.svg")
```

Comment: Thanks! After a first test, this seems to return the desired coordinates. So, `svg2paths()` was the missing part.

Comment: This looks reasonable, but would just using the built-in sort function be better, efficiency-wise?

Answer (score 0):

This simple package will do the job:  [svgpathtools](https://pypi.org/project/svgpathtools/)

Here is an example:

```py
from svgpathtools import parse_path

path = 'M 0,0 H 4.681 V 0.234 H 0 V 0 m 2.457,-2.223 v 4.68 H 2.223 v -4.68 h 0.234'
path_alt = parse_path(path)
print(path_alt.bbox())

# output: (0.0, 4.681, -2.223, 2.457)
```

Comment: Thanks. This is nice, however, I'm not just having a single path, but a full SVG document of which I want to know the bounding box. So, then probably I first would have to extract all paths of the SVG and then find the min and max coordinates of all these boxes. I need to try if this really will give the total bounding box or if there are more things to consider. What about circles, rectangles and other non-path objects?