# Remove white area around 3d plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, matplotlib-3d

I created a surface plot of a gaussian using matplotlib:

```py
num_pts = 1000
σ = 1.5

x = np.linspace(-5, 5, num_pts)
kernel1d = np.exp(-np.square(x) / (2 * σ * σ))
kernel2d = np.outer(kernel1d, kernel1d)

X, Y = np.meshgrid(x, x)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(6,6), subplot_kw={"projection":"3d"})
ax.plot_surface(X, Y, kernel2d, cmap="viridis", linewidth=0, antialiased=True)
ax.set(xticks=[], yticks=[], zticks=[])
ax.grid(False)
ax.axis('off')

fig.savefig("test.svg", format="svg", transparent=True)
```

The output has a lot of dead space around the actual plot.

[image]

I tried `layout=tight` which did not have any effect.

How can I maximize the size of the surface withing the figure assuming no need for any axis: ticks, labels, grid, etc...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can play around with the `pad_inches` value:

```
fig.savefig("test.svg", format="svg", transparent=True, bbox_inches='tight', pad_inches=-0.4)
```

Otherwise, perhaps you can try getting the bounding box containing the paths, and set the axes limits based on that: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76076555/7750891

Answer (score 1):

Setting the limits on the axes will functionally zoom you in and out when defining your plot. The `layout=tight` affects the white space around the plot or in the case of subplots will effectively pack them closer.

```
# change the limits of the axes to zoom in
ax.set_xlim(-2, 2)
ax.set_ylim(-2, 2)
ax.set_zlim(0, 1)
```

Results in:

[image: MatPlotLib Zoomed in Plot Example]

If it is whitespace around the plot area you wish to remove then

```
# remove everything surrounding the plot
fig.tight_layout(pad=0)
```

Will result in:

[image: Matplotlib no Borders Plot]

Comment: I want to remove that white space, not zoom in.

Comment: As in have a transparent background?

Comment: If you wish to remove the bounding box around the plot as if you were to crop the image then this post may be more relevant to you. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14908576/how-to-remove-frame-from-a-figure

Comment: I would like the area of the axis to be bigger in the figure. There is too much space around the axis.

Comment: In that second example the plot area is the whole area of the figure?

Comment: I have adjusted the answer to more closely align with what I think you are looking for

Comment: In the 2nd example you zoomed in. Think if you could crop the figure not the axis.

Comment: That still has the first set of changes applied but there is nothing in that image other than the plot area