# Scale svg vector image using python

Tags: python-3.x, svg

I'm currently trying to write a python script that will automate create fonts in inkscape.  I'm capturing my handwriting font using a remarkable2 tablet to capture the vector coordinates.  I'm exporting the file out to an svg file.  I have a python script that removes all layers from the file and places the paths at the root of the document.  When the vector images are exported from the remarkable2, let say the letter A for example, it has a position and size of X:167.996 Y:86.660 W:32.623 H:38.221 unit:px.  I need to scale the image so that it is moved to position and size X:126 Y:338 W:504 H:620 unit:px.  I need to be able to automate this for all the remaining characters such as A-Z, a-z, and numbers.

I've tried using the python built in xml tools to parse the xml file.  I've been able to extract the  tag and get the d="coordinates".  However, I don't know how to scale it correctly to get the correct values for each coordinate.  I've tried searching google and using AI tools to get an idea but have been unsuccessful.  I've looked at the svg2paths library but didn't really see anything in there that would help scale or resize the vector image.

Comment: if you want to scale/translate something in SVG you'd add a transform e.g. transform="scale(2) translate(10, 100)"

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

For now it will be the short answer. I guess that you already researched if there are any Python packages that has this functionality.

In JavaScript we can use [getBBox()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SVGGraphicsElement/getBBox) to the the size and position of an SVG element. In [svgpathtools](https://pypi.org/project/svgpathtools/) you can find something similar -- see this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76076555/322084. This is useful in this case because you need to know the bounding box of the path. With that, you know how much a path need to be scaled.

The path "lives in" a coordinate system. If the path was a square and the top left corner was a 0,0 and the top right corner was at 0,10 and you would like to scale the path 1.5, the top left corner would stay at 0,0 and the top right corner would move to 0,15. Lets imagine that there was a point in between the left and the right corner. Initially it would be at 0,5. When scaled up it has moved to 0,7.5 -- so, only half as much as the right corner. So, what you need to do is, for each point in the path to find out where it is located according to the overall bounding box and then move it accordingly.

Then there are the [path commands](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/d#path_commands) (m, M, l, L, c, C etc.). All the commands with lowercase letters have relative points defined. Maybe it is a good idea to "translate" them into absolute points first (so, with the uppercase letter).